# Connection between ASP.NET Core + MySQL at Docker Compose

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, docker, docker-compose

I'm with an error in connection between ASP.NET Core 6.0 and a MySQL Database in Docker containers.

Error:

```
workwise-aspnet-mvc-mysql-csharpemployeecrud-1  |        ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

workwise-aspnet-mvc-mysql-csharpemployeecrud-1  |          at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 433
workwise-aspnet-mvc-mysql-csharpemployeecrud-1  |
```

When running the application using `dotnet run` I can connect at the database at the container and make all CRUD operations as usual, but when running `docker compose up` and accessing the app by the container it does not work.

I suspect that is something different in the ConnectionString or something like that, but i couldn't discover yet.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  csharpemployeecrud:
    image: csharpemployeecrud
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5255:5255

  db:
    container_name: 'employee_csharp'
    image: mysql:8.0.29
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 3307:3306
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
```

This is my `Program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CSharp_EmployeeCrud.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3307;user=root;password=root;database=employee_csharp";
var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 29));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(
    dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
                .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                // The following three options help with debugging, but should
                // be changed or removed for production.
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors()
);
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Just in case, this is the repository at the "docker" branch: https://github.com/brunogroth/Workwise-ASPNET-MVC-MYSQL/tree/docker

About the connectionString, i've also tried to pass the following parameters, without success:

```
connectionString = "server=db;port=3307;user=root;password=root;database=employee_csharp"
```

```
connectionString = "server=db;port=3306;user=root;password=<PASSWORD>;database=employee_csharp"
```

```
connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=<PASSWORD>;database=employee_csharp"
```

Also tryied to pass the connectionString without `port` parameter. Nothing new.

Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the connection string you tried:

```
connectionString = "server=db;port=3307;user=root;password=root;database=employee_csharp"
```

and also add the database to the docker-compose.yaml file

`MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_csharp`

as well as delete the command for testing purposes.

```
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

You could also try to connect via a DB-Viewer tool to ensure that the db is accessable from outside the container.

Comment: I did it like this:

`db:
    container_name: 'employee_csharp'
    image: mysql:8.0.29
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=employee_csharp
      - TZ=America/Sao_Paulo`

and like this:

`db:
    container_name: 'employee_csharp'
    image: mysql:8.0.29
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_csharp
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo`

Same error.